# Strict convexity of $x \log x$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I'd like to show that $\tilde{f}: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} \quad x \mapsto x \log x$ is strictly convex. $\tilde{f}$ is the continuation of $f(x) = x \log x$ to include $x=0$. We can do that because $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x \log x = 0$, which can be shown by using L'Hôpitals rule. Because

$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2} f(x) = \frac{1}{x} > 0 \quad x>0 $$

this is certainly true for $f$. But is it also true for $\tilde{f}$? I think it should because the second derivative goes to $+\infty$ (which is positve) as $x$ is approaching $0$ but I'm unsure whether it is a problem that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: It should be enough to see this on $x \in [0, 1/2]$. There however, you can invert $y = x \log x$, and the inverse is strictly convex; that is, the graph does not touch the secant (except in two points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(X,X\ln X)$, i.e. $y=x\ln X$.

Between $0$ and $X$ (both excluded), we have $x\ln x<x\ln X,$ don't we ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have mentioned, that I've already shown it using that definition. I'm just wondering whether you can also show it with the "second derivative>0"-property. I'm unsure because the limit does not exist.

Comment: With a derivative going to $+\infty$ (for $0^+$), you are on the safe side, as this is $>0$.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $\tilde{f}$ is strictly convex we need to show that

$$\tilde{f}(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)<t\tilde{f}(x_1)+(1-t)\tilde{f}((1-t)x_2), \forall x_1,x_2\in[0,\infty) (x_1\ne x_2),\forall t\in (0,1).$$

If $x_1,x_2\ne 0$ it is a consequence of the fact that the second derivative is strictly positive. So, assume $x_2=0.$ Then you need to show that

$$\tilde{f}(tx_1)<t\tilde{f}(x_1),\:\forall x_1\in[0,\infty),\forall t\in (0,1).$$ That is,

$$tx_1 \log(tx_1)<tx_1\log x_1,\:\forall x_1\in[0,\infty),\forall t\in(0,1),$$ which is a consequence of $\log$ being strictly increasing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have mentioned, that I've already shown it using that definition. I'm just wondering whether you can also show it with the "second derivative>0"-property. I'm unsure because the limit does not exist.